# Django model React

Tags: django, reactjs, model

I'm trying some Django + React stuff and I'm a bit confused with the particular role of Django model in this scheme.

As I can understand Django model provide smooth way to create some typical forms by users of the site (please correct me). And I can't feel the edge of what should be hardcoded and what I need to store in model.

In case of React (I'm trying to connect react with django through api via djangorestframework) should I create a model for Header? And store bg image with it and my slogans. I feel it's should be purely in frontend. But next section with 3 typical screens (they will be listed horizontally and swap each other). They are just copy of each other with different data (title, bg, fg, text, link), for me it seems closer to model usage. But model initially empty and if I want to get this data from model I firstly need to somehow store this data to model.

So in general my question is what the right cases for using Django models and when it's no needed. And if it possible with applying to my example to better understanding for me )
ofc I searched this info widely but so far can't create clear understanding by myself.
   Thanks )

Answer (score 0):

You might actually be in search of a headless CMS.

To combine React and Django and still use a CMS to allow administrating text blocks and images, Django Wagtail's StreamField is a good choice.

https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0/topics/streamfield.html

See for example our company's homepage: https://www.blu-beyond.com. It runs on Django Wagtail, having JS animated text blocks that are administered in the CMS (just jQuery and other JS libs, no React, in this case).

Django Wagtail offers a JSON API, as well, that can be used in React:
https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.8/advanced_topics/api/v2/usage.html#fetching-content

It also offers a GraphQL API.

Comment: Thanks I'll read more about it maybe it's what I'm looking for )